# Conflicting versions of dependencies in JavaScript/AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, dependency-management

My earlier question was closed before I had the chance to add more clarity to it.

Might be a very basic question, but if I am using a particular version of a dependency, for example 1.x of dependency1, in my angular directive, and I package this directive to be used as a third party directive in an app that uses version 2.x of the same dependency1, how will the behavior be? I want to understand how shared directives work with multiple apps that might use a different version of a dependency that the directive is using.

I should probably make myself clear that I’m not asking about versions of angular. Let’s say I’m using bootstrap v3.3.7 in my directive whereas another app that uses my directive is using v3.1.1 of bootstrap. I want to understand how this would work and if there would be any conflicts.

Comment: what dependency manager do you use? once it's bower - it's harder(but still possible once you use alias for once of the versions). but once it's npm or yarn it should be as simple as using nested package.json. and for sure you will need some bundler to use `require(dependencyLibraryOfConcreteVersion)`

Comment: Virtually impossible to answer without specifics. At least document what you know works ... if not in package manager json file in some place that other users have access to like a repo